# update people and group list item by name and dont have user id/user name/email id Sharepoint 2013 by providing name in JSOM

Tags: user-profile, jsom, splistitem, user-profile-property, user-accounts

In my current scenario am having an excel with all the metadata and person name. This details I have to upload to Sharepoint 2013 list using JSOM.

Am not sure how to handle people and group column with the name. 
Ex: name: Mukesh which need to be inserted into the list where as the column type is people and group. Here I don't have any user id/email address/ user name.

Comment: The users name is not unique so you will have a hard task if you have any users with the same names

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer: We cannot do this.

In my scenario I try to get the email ID of the user and with the email ID I managed the code.